# floating point accuracy with bash

Tags: macos, bash

I have:

```
DIFF=$(( ($END - $START) / 60 ))
echo "Build took $DIFF minutes"
```

My output for 1:30 minutes is:

```
Build took 1 minutes
```

How do I employ floating point here so that my output will be:

```
Build took 1.50 minutes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use bc to get precision

example:

```
kent$  echo "scale=2;(190-100)/60"|bc
1.50
```

replace hardcoded number with your variables.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think bash supports floating point. You can use the `bc` command instead:

```
DIFF=$(bc <<< "scale=2; ($END - $START) / 60")
echo "Build took $DIFF minutes"
```

Comment: `$(bc <<< "scale=2;($END - $START) / 60")` you mean